# Does everything depend on the topology spaces are under?

Tags: general-topology

I'm sorry, I'm doing a lot of topology in very little days so I'm getting confused. It seems everything depends on which topology spaces are under, but does that mean some spaces are homeomorphic under one topology, while not homeomorphic under another?

Comment: Yes. Homeomorphism means that you have a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse. You can't even define what it means to be continuous without equipping the sets with a topology.

Comment: Thanks! So every time we talk about objects in R^n being homeomorphic we mean under the euclidian topology?

Comment: (when we don't specify under which topology of course)

Comment: Yes, if not otherwise specified, we'd understand the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be the metric topology given by Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "space" is a set with a topology, so some spaces are homeomorphic *because* there is a bicontinuous bijection between them. If you give a space another topology, then it's another space.

That said, there are a lot of things that do not depend on a topology, for instance the cardinality of the underlying set, and other properties thereof.

Basically a space is a pair

$$
\langle X, \tau\rangle
$$

where $\tau\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a set of subsets of $X$ which is closed under some operations. When you consider two topologies over the same set, you are actually talking about two spaces, even if the underlying set is the same.

On the other side, using the same underlying set sometimes helps in visualization of the space, as "the real line with half-line topology" or "the cantor set in $[0,1]$ with the subset topology" is much easier to grasp than any abstract description.

Answer (score 2):

A *topological space* is a set $X$ together with a *topology* on $X$.  To say that two topological spaces are *homeomorphic*, we mean that these pairs of objects are in a particular relationship to each other: there is a bijection between the underlying sets of the topological spaces which moves the open sets in one topology to open sets in the other, and *vice versa*.

As some trivial examples, there are many different topolgies on $\mathbb{N}$:

- the *discrete topology*, defined to be the family of *all* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$;
- the *anti-discrete topology*, defined to be $\{ \varnothing , \mathbb{N} \}$;
- the *cofinite topology*, defined to be $\varnothing$ together with all $U \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{N} \setminus U$ is finite;
- the *initial topology*, defined to be the family of all initial segments of $\mathbb{N}$ ($\varnothing$, $\{ 0 \}$, $\{ 0 ,1 \}$, $\{ 0 , 1 , 2 \}$, $\ldots$) ;
- the *final topology*, defined to be $\varnothing$ together with all final segments of $\mathbb{N}$ ($\{ 0 , 1 , 2, \ldots \}$, $\{ 1 , 2, \ldots \}$, $\ldots$).

It is not too difficult to show that no pair of these topologies are homeomorphic, even though the underlying set is the same.  For example, since no nonempty finite set is open in the cofinite topology, it cannot be homeomorphic to the discrete topology.

Often when writing about topological spaces we omit explicit mention of the topology under consideration, and say things like "Let $X$ be a topological space...".  This is often to save the reader from obfuscating notation and terminology.  When this happens, it is generally safe to assume that *some* appropriate topology has been chosen, and is fixed throughout the argument at hand.